# where can I find the avro.schema.url within the hive meta store?

Tags: hive

I am trying to locate the property avro.schema.url that is part of the table meta data when a table is created by specifying the location to a avro schema file  for  some avro data in s3 or hdfs. I am able to see it in the output when I run the describe extended table command, but within the metastore database, where is this property stored?  I searched the table_params for that particular table_id and did not find it ?

Answer (score 0):

found it, its in SERDE_PARAMS table